# MacBook Pro 2015 Keyboard and trackpad not detected once booted into operating system

Tags: keyboard, mojave, trackpad

Ever since I updated my computer to macOS Mojave I’ve been experiencing issues. The issues all started at the same time and they include:

1. Computer crashing after opening lid(Computer Transitioning from Sleep State
2. Trackpad feedback(the click from the Taptic Engine) stops randomly while using the computer
3. Trackpad and keyboard not detected by OS after reboot.

In the past most of the issues I was having were simply fixed by resetting the SMC or by simply rebooting the computer. Unfortunately at this point no matter how many times I reset the SMC, or reboot the computer, the internal keyboard and trackpad are not responding, even though the trackpad still makes a “click” from the Taptic Engine when clicked.

I’ve attempted many things including rebooting the computer, SMC reset, PRAM/NVRAM reset(unsuccessful), system hardware test(unsuccessful), etc...

The reason certain resets and tests were unsuccessful is because the OS is unable to detect the keyboard, but others like the SMC do no require the OS to preform the reset so it functions.

Does anyone have any ideas on ways to solve this issue that doesn’t involve completely reinstalling macOS?

Computer:
MacBook Pro Mid 2015 13”

Comment: Try booting in to Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting) and/or Recovery Mode (Hold `Command-R`).  If the keyboard works fine in any of these environments, it's likely not a hardware problem.  Before wiping your drive and reinstalling, try installing and booting to a USB flash disk (32GB is sufficient).  Again, if the problem goes away, you've got your answer.

Comment: @Allan Neither of these were functional and the computer continued to boot to the login screen. This seems to look like a hardware issue, but if resets like a SMC reset functions, wouldn’t this mean that the keyboard is functional and that it’s software?

Comment: It likely means your keyboard is good, but there's still an underlying hardware issue.  An SMC reset is setting the power management chip back to it's factory default state.  If components work, then fail after an SMC reset it probably means components aren't getting enough voltage/power when required.  That being the case, it's time to take it in for service.

Comment: For this issue, I’m not sure if the SMC reset actually fixed any issue, all I know is that it shows the keyboard itself isn’t damaged. I don’t know if it’s actually done anything to fix the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem, we took it to a service and they said this is a common problem with MBP2015.

There's a cable that connects the motherboard with the touchpad.

That cable can die over time.

They swapped it out and we could pick up the machine and it was up and running with working touchpad/keyboard in just 2 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it. For everyone having this issue, try solution from [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295):
`Press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the power button at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. If you have a MacBook Pro with Touch ID, the Touch ID button is also the power button.`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was indeed with the cable that connects the touchpad with the mainboard:

[image]

The cable could die over time as @EpicPandaForce said, or because of oxidation (if you spilled water on the keyboard).

Replacing the cable will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn’t a hardware problem, you could try resetting the VRAM by booting up and holding <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
I’ve been having this problem with my own MacBook and this has worked for me recently.